# OpenGL smooth glTranslatef animation | LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

Good evening. I am trying to smoothly move rectangle shape across the screen with glTranslatef. The concept is Windows 10 notifications. You know that they appear from right bottom of the screen, ease in-out animation and so on. I am trying to recreate it. But I dont know how can I achieve it.

Here is a basic requirement:

- Move slowly, not in one frame. For example Windows 10 notifications. They move slowly, ease in-out (if possible).

I would appreciate any help, any tip, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could start by finding the height (or width, as needed) define and initialize a variable (say, x) at half the height (again, or width) and move the notif x pixels up, divide x by 2, and raise the notif by 2 again, and repeat a number of times so that the notif doesn't take to long to appear, or look awkward, and finally move to the final desired position. (If you don't like how it looks, you can subtract x by 1 or some other number instead.)